# mysql if statement on same row across a Group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, group-by

I have a GIANT join which has a problem.

Now to test it I made a test table like

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `cartarticleID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
    `cartarticle_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `testValue` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Now i populated the first table with just one entry and joined it with the other one.

[image]

And the other is like this

[image]

Now the query is made like this

```
select 
    table1.cartarticleID,
    if(table2.testValue = 1, 1, null) as lol,
    if(table2.testValue = 3, 1, null) as lol3
from
    table1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 ON table1.cartarticleID = table2.cartarticle_id
```

And it produces this.

[image]

But here lies the problem the query has a group by cartarticleID and the crap dous get only the first entry and noth the other one in one row like:

```
select 
    table1.cartarticleID,
    if(table2.testValue = 1, 1, null) as lol,
    if(table2.testValue = 3, 1, null) as lol3
from
    table1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 ON table1.cartarticleID = table2.cartarticle_id
GROUP by cartarticleID
```

And there we have it. Lol3 will be empty.

How can I get lol and lol3 to be filled there to??

Comment: The GROUP BY is for aggregate values, such as summing up fields that are not in the GROUP BY. It can also be used to eliminate duplicates, which is what is happening here. The values from lol and lol3 are from an undefined row. Which value do you want to pick, or do you want to get the sum of them for each cartarticleID?

Comment: @fancyPants has answered my question, i needed to spread the values from one row to diferend rows via conditions. which he did splendidly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), if you don't want to get a random row of each group.

```
select 
    table1.cartarticleID,
    max(if(table2.testValue = 1, 1, null)) as lol,
    max(if(table2.testValue = 3, 1, null)) as lol3
from
    table1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 ON table1.cartarticleID = table2.cartarticle_id
GROUP by cartarticleID
```